# Categorising continous data in logistic regression

Tags: logistic, continuous-data

If a predictor in a logistic regression is not discriminating between 'goods' and 'bads' for most of the range and is discriminating only at higher or lower values (monotonic), should the variable be used as continuous or as a dummy indicating the range in which it is predictive?

Answer (score 3):

Seems to me that categorizing just throws away information: so I wouldn't do unless a very good reason could be given for the problem at hand.

But then, the data I work with is subject to quite some noise and thus you'd really loose good information by a cut (either you "contaminate" your indication-of-bad level by good samples with just noise into the bad direction or you lose some of them as they end up in the indication-of-good level).

And, for values far away from the decision boundary you'd loose the indication that the sample is really far away from the decision boundary from that predictor's point of view.

Comment: Categorizing doesn't always damage the information used for the fit in a (generalized) linear model. For example, if the relationship between $x$ and $y$ is highly non-linear, then you can use the data much more effectively by categorizing $x$ and then estimating it's effect as you would any factor in regression. This might more adequately capture the non-linear aspects of the relationship (if sufficiently many roughly homogeneous categories are made) than calculating a linear fit to the original continuous measurement.